# How can I edit tomcat configuration files inside the docker container?

Tags: docker

I am trying to nano/vim inside a docker container to edit the tomcat config files but i am getting an error that nano/vim is unknown command. I tried to yum install, still yum is unknown comand. How do I go about it

Comment: Try vi. What is your base image? `yum` is centos pm.

Answer (score 2):

The most common editor is `vi`. To install some packages into your container you have to know it's base image. Most of distros create a special file in `/etc/` with all necessary information: *something*-release, you can find it out with this command:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

And then use the package manager of current distro.

- for Alpine it will be `apk update && apk add vim`.
- for Ubuntu/Debian - `apt update && apt install vim`.
- for Centos/RedHat/Fedora - `yum install vim`
- etc

Comment: @alex.w, you are welcome! Feel free to rate this answer:)